# How can I verifying a footer text using selenium Junit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, automated-tests, junit4

I want to verify a text in the footer. I normally copied the XPath locator and find element then get the text of the element, but nothing happens for this code part in Junit.

From this website I need to get the footer text:

https://www.qaagility.com/

Here is the code I am using for this. I know there is another way of doing it.

```
public class QAA_mock3 {
     private WebDriver driver;
      private Map<String, Object> vars;
      JavascriptExecutor js;
      @Before
      public void setUp() {
        driver = utils.HelperFunctions.createAppropriateDriver("Chrome");
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      }
    

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String ExpTitle = "QAAgility" ;
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        By TwitterLink = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"custom_html-4\"]/div/div[1]/a[2]");
        By footer = By.xpath("//div[@id='footer']");
        By imglogo = By.cssSelector("img.header-image");
        
        driver.get(" https://www.qaagility.com");
        System.out.println("Loaded page...");
        
        String ActTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("page Title..."+ ActTitle);
        if(ActTitle.contains(ExpTitle)) {
            System.out.println("Verified the title for ..."+ ExpTitle);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Title verification went wrong...");
        
        WebElement imgSize = driver.findElement(imglogo);
        Dimension imageSize = imgSize.getSize();
        int Height = imageSize.getHeight();
        int Width = imageSize.getWidth();
        
        
        System.out.println("The size of the Logo is : Width = "+ Width + "; Height = "+Height);
        
        WebElement Twitter = driver.findElement(TwitterLink);
        String Href = Twitter.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println("Twitter Link is :"+ Href);
        
        WebElement footerText = driver.findElement(footer);
        System.out.println("WebElement for footer is"+ footerText);
        actions.moveToElement(footerText).build().perform();
        
        String FTText = footerText.getText();
        System.out.println("Footer Text is :"+ FTText);
        
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of this test? Do you run in an timeout exception because Selenium can't find the element?

Comment: As footer element has no Id attribute, element is not located. Please use either By.classname or in xpath class attribute as :
By footer = By.xpath("//div[@class='copyright-bar']");

Comment: Also as corresponding text of footer has extra space , for better readability don't forget to use trim on text, until unless you want to print all spaces as well
**String FTText = footerText.getText().trim()**;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrong define footer locator:

```
By footer = By.xpath("//div[@id='footer']");
```

Try this:

```
By footer = By.className("copyright-bar")
```